# Rspec how to add booleans via loop in and_return()

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
allow(object).to receive(:method).and_return(true, false, true, true, true)
```

How can I add these boolean values via loop?

My code is right now look like this

```
allow(object).to receive(:method).and_return(booleans[0], booleans[1], booleans[2], booleans[3], booleans[4])
```

Comment: I am not aware of this but can you return more than 1 value in `and_return`? How does that work?

Comment: Got it. Did the below solution worked for you @user3743992?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Not sure if you can return more than 1 value from here
allow(object).to receive(:method).and_return(*booleans)
```

if number of elements in `booleans` match the number of arguments i.e. 5.

If your method returns an array of booleans, then you can do this instead:

```
allow(object).to receive(:method).and_return(booleans)
```

Comment: Thank you very much your solution (*booleans) worked.

Comment: You can't match the number of arguments – [`and_return`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value) takes a _variable_ number of arguments. Each one is used as the return value for subsequent calls to the stubbed method.

Comment: Cool. I was not aware of it though. Thanks. :)